# javascript interval with an ever longer time

Tags: javascript

I made a code for an animation on the button

```
cta.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                audio.play()
                audio.volume = .06;

                imgs[0].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
                
                setTimeout(() => {
                    imgs[2].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
                }, 150);
                
                setTimeout(() => {
                    imgs[1].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
                }, 200);
                
                setTimeout(() => {
                    imgs[5].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
                }, 250);
                
                setTimeout(() => {
                    imgs[3].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
                }, 300);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    imgs[4].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
                }, 600);
            }, 100);
        });
```

But this is not very pleasant.

How to improve this code ?? Make a setInterval only and make this value increase with each execution ??

Comment: Would CSS animations or transitions suit better?

Comment: `setTimeout` only guarantees that the code will not execute before the specified amount of time. It does not mean that the code will execute exactly when the timeout expires. See this [page](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/#when-i-say-so-execution-settimeout) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of improvement I can see is to use a for loop:

```js
cta.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    audio.play()
    audio.volume = .06;

    let times = [0, 200, 150, 300, 600, 250]

    times.forEach(function(let idx in times) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          imgs[idx].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
        }, times[idx]);
      }
    }, 100);)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly better version of code:

```
cta.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        audio.play()
        audio.volume = .06;

        imgs[0].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
        transformImage(imgs[2], 150);
        transformImage(imgs[1], 200);
        transformImage(imgs[5], 250);
        transformImage(imgs[3], 300);
        transformImage(imgs[4], 600);
    }, 100);
});

function transformImage(img, interval) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        img.style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
    }, interval);
}
```

Further improvement:

```
cta.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            audio.play()
            audio.volume = .06;

            imgs[0].style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
            let offset = 150;
            imgs.forEach(img => transformImage(img, offset+=50));
        }, 100);
    });
    
    function transformImage(img, interval){
            setTimeout(() => {
                img.style.transform = "translate(0, 0)";
        }, interval);
    }
```